# What formatting tools are available for GLSL?

Tags: formatting, format, glsl, clang-format

I've recently been needing to review GLSL code, and I'm looking to enforce formatting conventions. Are there any tools like `clang-format` for GLSL where I can specify a config file and have it auto-format? Or, since GLSL is C-like, should I just use `clang-format` itself and hope for the best?

I need to enforce things like spacing, brace style, and indentation.

Comment: GLSL is close enough to C and C++ that a sufficiently non-smart formatter (one that doesn't actually parse C/C++) should be able to do the job. And any tool that can handle byte encoding stuff should be able to deal with GLSL text.

Answer (score 5):

clang-format seems to handle GLSL fine:

```
 $ clang-format -i myshader.glsl
```

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html

Answer (score 3):

GLSLX, a GLSL type checker, formatter, and minifier:

http://evanw.github.io/glslx/